# Record rows updated through SSIS execute task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, rowcount

I have a package which connects to `SourceDB1` and execute an update statement that updates DestDB2. Now I have many such source DB and destination DB which has the similar structure.  For this I have for each loop container within which the execute SQL task is placed. Now, since the sourceDB connection varies , I have created a variable named `SourceConnString`. Likewise, the update query is also within a variable named `UpdateVariable`. I created `UpdateVariable` because source and destination are two different databases.

Now I need to save the number of records that are updated in the execute sql task each time. The records count should be inserted into a table or flat file whichever is easy.

I saw tutorials how to do this without using  an update through  variable. Is there any way we could return the count of rows in my situation.

Comment: Have you considered using @@rowcount function within execute sql task ?

Comment: I didn't use it as SqlSourceType in the Execute SQl task is a variable.

Comment: Should I use @@rowcount inside the variable along with the update query? Do you think it will work?

Comment: it should work, i would say create a table in the database with default getdate(), and count columns. Insert values of @@rowcount into the table.

Comment: You can use @@RowCount, check the link that i provided in my answer. It contains a step-by-step tutorial

Comment: I am testing with @@rowcount.The rows are updated, count of number of rows updated are stored in a variable. Then I insert the value of this variable to a log table. Now the log table has either blank or * getting inserted. Wonder why.

Comment: I used a script task to display value of "NumberOfRecords". And it shows -1.

Comment: How insert to log table is done?

Comment: Using another execute SQL Task, the insert statement is executed. Variable with rowcount is passed as parameter to the insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following. A new variable “**Newupquery**” is created and below code snippet is the value assigned to this variable and which is used within the execute SQl task.

---

```
DECLARE @UpdateRowCnt INT;
update countcheck
set [Base Unit of Measure] = 'PCS-1'
where [Base Unit of Measure] = 'PCS';
SELECT @UpdateRowCnt=@@ROWCOUNT;
Select @UpdateRowCnt
```

The above  **execute SQl task** is executed and the result set is set to variable “**UpdateRowCount**”.

The next step is another **Execute SQL Task**, which inserts the value of the variable **UpdateRowCount** to the log table in a stage server.  The value of variable **UpdateRowCount** was passed to insert statement using the parameter setting in **Execute SQl Task.**

Comment: This is weird. what is the difference with my suggestion? why assigning the value to a variable solved the issue??

Comment: Even I have the same concern. I followed exactly the steps in the link you posted. I get either -1 or 0 as the row count result. When I check the table, there are 100 rows updated.

Comment: Really i don't know why this is happening, anyway you have to mark this answer as accepted. Even if it is yours

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ExecValueVariable** property, in Execute SQL Task it stores number of records affected by SQL command. You have to specify variable name at **ExecValueVariable** property or pick it up from drop-down as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Even though i tried this method, am unable insert the rowount variable value to a log table.

Comment: You can get the execvariable value containing rowcount from SQL Task, and insert it into another SQL command. Then you can execute it, inserting desired value in your table.
ExecVariable itself can get you number of rows updated; you decide what to do next.

Comment: Never knew about this property, that's super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Select query with `@@ROWCOUNT` after the UPDATE query, like the following:

```
UPDATE SomeTable Set SomeColumn = SomeValue;

SELECT @@RowCount as NumberOfAffectedRecords
```

And use a Single Row ResultSet to get the value.

**The following article contains a Step-by-step tutorial**

- [RowCount for Execute SQL Task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/rowcount-for-execute-sql-statement.html)